# uWebSockets http serves too slow

Tags: c++, c++17, uwebsockets

I've cloned [uWebSockets](https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets), wrote the following file.

```
#include <App.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uWS::App()
            .get("/*", [](auto *res, auto *req) {
                res->end("Hello world!");
            })
            .listen(3000, [](auto *token) {
                if (token) {
                    std::cout << "Listening on port " << 3000 << std::endl;
                }
            })
            .run();

    std::cout << "Failed to listen on port 3000" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Built it with

```
make -C uWebSockets/uSockets
g++ -flto -O3 -Wconversion -std=c++17 -IuWebSockets/src -IuWebSockets/uSockets/src main.cpp -o main uWebSockets/uSockets/*.o -lz -lssl -lcrypto -luv
```

When I do a benchmark, this is what I get.

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   116.928 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      68000 bytes
HTML transferred:       12000 bytes
Requests per second:    8.55 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       11692.844 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       116.928 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.57 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    3   2.6      2      10
Processing:  8923 11690 921.2  11995   12012
Waiting:        0    1   1.3      0      10
Total:       8923 11693 921.7  11999   12012

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  11999
  66%  12001
  75%  12002
  80%  12003
  90%  12006
  95%  12008
  98%  12010
  99%  12011
 100%  12012 (longest request)
```

If I set concurrency to 1, this happens

```
Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   61.655 seconds
Complete requests:      5
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      408 bytes
HTML transferred:       72 bytes
Requests per second:    0.08 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       12330.911 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       12330.911 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.01 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Did I do something wrong? Did I miss something? Shouldn't it be faster?

PS. I'm running it on single thread.

Comment: It looks like your benchmark client is keeping open 100 concurrent connections. Since there's only a single thread to serve those connections, only a few will be served every second; the rest is just stuck waiting.

Comment: Should it really take that much time just to say "Hello world!"? Even expressjs can do better than this in node. Something to do with async?

Comment: Please benchmark with a single concurrent connection first before drawing conclusions.

Comment: Added single concurrent connection stats. Way worse.

Comment: You should probably figure out why that is, first. Obvious candidates: `uWebSockets/uSockets` was not compiled with optimizations, or something very weird networking-wise. Can you check what is happening syscall-wise with strace or equivalent?

Comment: This is how examples are written, I tried 16 threads in all my CPU cores and apparently each request takes 8s-12s. I'm running it on my local PC so there's no network latency. The issue must be inside the library. I've tried the examples that are given in the repository. They perform similarly.

Comment: And what tool are you using to test? Your example server only supports HTTP, not websockets

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223509/discussion-between-rocky-and-botje).

Comment: Note that SO etiquette prefers that you create a self-answer instead of editing the question with "solved".

Comment: Copying from the chat: You may have been bitten by the problem described [here](https://reinir.github.io/articles/http-slim-and-apachebench.html). 
Can you try explicitly calling `close` after `end` to close the socket?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't make a difference even when response has "Connection: close" header.

Comment: I believe ab is waiting for you to close the connection, for some reason. Oh well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using apache benchmark tool(`ab`) and it was slow, not the program. Used bomberdier and got this result

```
Bombarding http://127.0.0.1:3000/ with 1000000 request(s) using 5000 connection(s)
 1000000 / 1000000 [===============================================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00% 316582/s 3s
Done!
Statistics        Avg      Stdev        Max
  Reqs/sec    361230.80   54733.74  520938.19
  Latency       14.06ms     8.81ms   358.62ms
  HTTP codes:
    1xx - 0, 2xx - 1000000, 3xx - 0, 4xx - 0, 5xx - 0
    others - 0
  Throughput:    40.48MB/s
```